How to compare the first value to each subsequent value in SQL until a condition is met
I have a table in the general structure below:

What I would like to do is, compare the first row to the next row, until the difference between the dates meets some threshold, say 30 days. Then, once that row meets the threshold, I'd like to then test the next row against the subsequent row. It would look like this:
Result, using threshold of 30:

So to reiterate, its comparing the FIRST row to subsequent rows until some threshold is met. Then the count starts over at the first rep after that within the group to subsequent rows within the group.
I've tried this but so far I havent been able to get the right rowwise comparison to even implement the thresholding bit.
select *, 
case when lagdiff > 30 then 1 else 0
end as lag_flg from
(SELECT *, datediff(Date,lag) AS lagdiff from
(select ID, Date, lag(Date) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date
                    ) AS lag
from table


What is the current output and why is it wrong? (your current query looks to be on the right track at least)

The current logic only compares with the previous row value. However, the requirement is to compare with the last value which has date difference of 30 days.

You absolutely should be including sample input and output which gets the point across.  You haven't done that.

Hi Tim, I've shared the input and expected output as a screenshot.

I'm not sure it's possible to do with window functions, cause for each row you need to know result of previous calculations, specifically which row is being used as a starting point.
It is definitely possible to do with recursive cte:
create temp table data as
select d.d as ddate
from (values
    ('2023-11-14'::date),
    ('2024-01-25'::date),
    ('2024-02-01'::date),
    ('2024-02-04'::date),
    ('2024-02-11'::date),
    ('2024-03-04'::date)
) as d(d);

with recursive cte_calc as (
    select
        d.ddate as start_date,
        d.ddate as current_date,
        1 as flag
    from data as d
    where
        d.ddate = '2023-11-14'

    union all

    select
        case when p.ddate - d.start_date > 30 then p.ddate else d.start_date end as start_date,
        p.ddate as current_date,
        case when p.ddate - d.start_date > 30 then 1 else 0 end as flag
    from cte_calc as d
        inner join lateral (select tt.ddate from data as tt where tt.ddate > d.current_date order by tt.ddate asc limit 1) as p on true
)
select *
from cte_calc;

------------------------------
start_date  current_date  flag
2023-11-14  2023-11-14    1
2024-01-25  2024-01-25    1
2024-01-25  2024-02-01    0
2024-01-25  2024-02-04    0
2024-01-25  2024-02-11    0
2024-03-04  2024-03-04    1


Thanks @Roman. Looks like recursive CTE is not supported in spark sql
